# Disable automatic update for all Table of Contents (ToC) styles in Normal template (Word 2010+)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles, templates

I sometimes want to "start from scratch" by replacing whatever the current Word Normal file with a pristine new copy and then to customize it with my preferred settings.

The Normal file has all of the table of content (ToC) styles set to automatic updates.

As best I can tell, the only way to disable that setting is one-by-one, and that involves multiple steps (click the style, click Modify, toggle Automatic update, click Ok, repeat).

Is there an easy way to make the change to all ToC styles all at once; for example can the automatic updates:

- Be disabled for all of the ToC styles at the same time? or
- Be preserved and reused in a way that doesn't defeat the purpose of "starting clean"? (Importing from an earlier dotm, dotx, or dot file would all seem to be defeating the purpose; but maybe there's something stored in a library or other type of file?)

Environment: Multiple PCs with different versions of MSOffice on each.

Note: The automatic update setting for ToC styles has a long history. It appears to have "always been that way."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting to Automatically Update is a default setting on all TOC level styles. Someone in your organization did not do it, that's the way Microsoft set them in Word's Normal template.

There is not a supplied method to change settings on all of those styles at the same time. You can though use the Organizer function, accessed from the Developer tab on the Document Template button, to replace groups of styles that have already been altered in a document. The process for this would be:

1. Create a document and in it modify the nine TOC styles
2. Take that document to each machine and open it
3. Use the Organizer function of Word to copy the nine altered TOC styles to the Normal template of that computer.

The other method that can be used is a macro that you would run on each computer. Below is the macro you could use.

```
Sub UpdateTemplateStyles()
Dim sty As word.Style
Dim odocStyles As word.Styles
Dim oTemplate As word.Document

On Error GoTo errHandler
Set oTemplate = ActiveDocument.attachedTemplate.OpenAsDocument
Set odocStyles = oTemplate.Styles
For Each sty In odocStyles
    Select Case sty.Type
        Case wdStyleTypeParagraph
            Select Case sty.NameLocal
                Case "TOC 1", "TOC 2", "TOC 3", "TOC 4", _
                    "TOC 5", "TOC 6", "TOC 7", "TOC 8", "TOC 9"
                    sty.AutomaticallyUpdate = False
            End Select
    End Select
Next sty
oTemplate.SaveAs2 FileName:=oTemplate.FullName, AddToRecentFiles:=False
DoEvents
oTemplate.Close
Exit Sub

errHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "UpdateTemplateStyles"
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer is highly valuable because it (a) provided alternatives, (b) has well-written steps for each alternative, and (c) provided the actual macro for the second alternative.

Comment: @RJo Thank you, that is kind of you to say that. I'm glad to have helped.